# How to catch any Flutter exception

Tags: flutter, dart

My application generated code based off some user defined string. The resulting code may not be valid and could produce a UI tree which throws, e.g.,:

```dart
Widget parseUserInput();

parseUserInput('Flexible>Expanded')
=> Yields: Flexible(child: Expanded(child: Container())
```

This code throws in Flutter. The exception is caught by Flutter itself.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
...
```

I cannot catch this exception with `try/catch` because Flutter is already catching it. I also cannot catch it with MaterialApp's `ErrorWidget.builder` because that one doesn't seem to be triggered either.

Is there any other way to catch this? In an ideal world I'd do:

```
ErrorWidget(
    onError: revertToLastValidUserInput,
    child: WidgetBuilder(builder: (context) => parseUserInput(...)
)
)
```

Comment: Can't you create a filter or a warning for user input?

Comment: Not very reasonable to filter the user input for all possible errors. Also, I am not quite sure what all errors would even be.

Comment: I think the best way would be using the patterns which leads to an error, since even if you could write a widget to catch errors, what will you do for situations like this that always make an exception `Column>ErrorWidget>Expanded`. you need to wrap the whole app in a error widget and this will make debugging it hard

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to silence exceptions in this way.
Users should be aware about the error and in this case you could, for example, **validate the input** before it will be processed and **show an alert** to the user (Text(), dialog or something else).